# Yahoo API not returning stock price

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, stock

I've been using YQL to generate queries I can use in Excel for various data. It's been working just fine until recently...

For example, the following query ([Yahoo Stock query](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22yhoo%22)) only returns this:

> {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2017-08-28T18:05:42Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"stock":{"symbol":"yhoo"}}}}

As you can see, the price is not included in the result.. just that the 'symbol' is "yhoo". Well, no kidding, that's what I asked for....

Not really sure why I'm not getting the price back anymore.... does anyone see anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Edit. Here's the REST Query URL that YQL provides at the bottom of the page: [Yahoo Stock Price](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22yhoo%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)

Comment: What URL are you sending your request to?

Comment: Here's the URL that YQL gives me at the bottom of the page:  https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22yhoo%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Comment: That URL doesn't work for me. Add it into the question instead

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has discontinued their Yahoo Finance API service. So you won't be able to download stock quote in .csv format or using YQL.

Comment: They've discontinued a lot of things lately.  In fact I fear that Verizon (or whoever now own them) are just asset stripping them for anything that will make money and killing off the rest.  Over the coming months I'm going to be re-writing EVERYTHING I have that used ANYTHING on Yahoo, Finance, Weather, News, GeoBoss, YQL all of it, then I'm going to close my Email acct and walk away from them for good.  I don't see any future left in anything that carries the Yahoo Name if it doesn't generate any revenue.

Comment: Also, Yahoo messeger is dead too. Seems they're going to bankrupt unless other company acquire them.

Comment: Nothing to do with going bankrupt @dns , as you may know from the news, Yahoo was previously sold to the Verizon company in america.  Yahoo is no longer Yahoo in anything but name.  Verizon are a communications monopoly in the USA, and have been pointed out for being very greedy and uncaring in the past.  All they care about is what bit's of Yahoo they can keep, and make more money from, anything they can't make money from, will vanish eventually.  Anything that's currently being run free will eventually vanish, that's why I'm walking away now while I still can.

Comment: @shawty: I didn't know it was already bought by Verizon. I think I'm going to migrate my yahoo email account to something else.

Comment: If all the news sources are to be believed, the deal is now done.  Marissa has left, and with the usual golden handshake the CEO's seem to get for ruining companies these days.  First thing I did was go in and change all my "real" details to "faux-pa" ones.  I'll keep my Yahoo email, but it'll be used only for organisations I don't trust and spam from now on.